# Clear all Inputs with a button within ng-repeat table

Tags: angularjs

I´m new in AngularJS and I use a table which adds dynamic rows. Now I want to use a function to delete the contents of all the inputs with the ng-model item.taxOne and item.taxTwo, depending on the selected value.

For e.g.

Selection Tax none: All Inputs with ng-model item.taxOne and item.taxTwo should be cleared

Selection 1 Tax: All Inputs with ng-model item-taxTow should be cleared

Selection 2 Taxes: do nothing...

Unfortunately it do not work: My first approach (see the script below) was to delete all inputs of item-TaxOne. Already at this point, I get an error:

*Cannot set property 'taxOne' of undefined*

Thank you for your tips!

**Select HTML**

```
<select ng-model="taxOption">
  <option value="tax-none" selected="selected">   
  </option><option value="1 Tax" selected="selected">
  </option><option value="2 Taxes"></option>
</select>
```

**Table HTML**

```
<tbody >
<tr ng:repeat="item in invoice.items">
<td ng-hide=" taxOption=='tax-none' ">
    <input ng:model="item.taxOne">
</td>
<td ng-hide="taxOption=='tax-none' || taxOption=='1 Tax' ">
    <input  ng:model="item.taxTwo">
</td>
</tbody >
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [] ]);

app.controller('CtrlInvoice', ['$scope', '$translate', '$modal', '$window', '$filter', '$http', '$timeout', function($scope, $translate, $modal, $window, $filter, $http, $timeout) {
$scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.invoice.items.push({
        taxOne : '',
        taxTwo : ''
    });
};

$scope.reset = function() {
   $scope.item.taxOne = '';
};
}])
```

Comment: You're missing some javascript here?

Comment: how is your javascript supposed to know which invoice to clear? And where are you calling reset()?

Comment: I call the reset() with a button (ng-click="reset()"). I have edited the script above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because that function in the controller doesn't see the `item` variable, which is only defined inside the repeater. This is because the `ng-repeat` directive has its own scope. (See the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).)

If you want to clear all the `taxOne` values of the repeated items, you should loop through them in the controller - meaning the `$scope.invoice.items` array that is in the controller's scope.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution to clear all inputs within the ng-repeat Controller. Thanks to MJV for the tip!

```
$scope.resetTaxOne = function() {
    var tItems = $scope.invoice.items;
    angular.forEach(tItems, function(item) {
        item.taxOne = "";
    });
};
```